EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt Error in OpenSSL Decryption
I'm working on a C program that uses the OpenSSL library to perform several cryptographic operations. However, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to decrypt a file using AES-128-ECB. The decryption process fails with the error EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt.
Here are the details of my implementation:
Decrypt a file (s83660-cipher.bin) using a key (s83660-source-key.bin) with AES-128-ECB.
Compute the SHA512/224 hash of the decrypted file and compare it with a provided hash (s83660-   digest.bin).
Encrypt the decrypted file with Camellia-256-OFB using another key (s83660-dest-key.bin).

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/camellia.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define SHA512_224_DIGEST_LENGTH 28

void handleErrors(void) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}

void decrypt_aes_128_ecb(const char *cipher_file, const char *key_file, const char *output_file) {
    FILE *cf = fopen(cipher_file, "rb");
    FILE *kf = fopen(key_file, "rb");
    FILE *of = fopen(output_file, "wb");

    if (!cf || !kf || !of) {
        perror("File error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Read key
    unsigned char key[16];
    if (fread(key, 1, 16, kf) != 16) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading key\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    key[0] = 0;  // Salting

    // Print key for debugging
    printf("Key after modification: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%02x", key[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Initialize decryption
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (!ctx) handleErrors();

    // Disable padding for manual handling
    if (EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0) != 1) handleErrors();

    if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ecb(), NULL, key, NULL) != 1) handleErrors();

    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned char plaintext[BUFFER_SIZE + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    int len;
    int plaintext_len = 0;

    while ((len = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, cf)) > 0) {
        int out_len;
        if (EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &out_len, buffer, len) != 1) handleErrors();
        fwrite(plaintext, 1, out_len, of);
        plaintext_len += out_len;
    }

    // Print intermediate plaintext length for debugging
    printf("Intermediate plaintext length: %d\n", plaintext_len);

    if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext, &len) != 1) {
        // Print specific OpenSSL error message
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        handleErrors();
    }
    fwrite(plaintext, 1, len, of);
    plaintext_len += len;

    printf("Final plaintext length: %d\n", plaintext_len);

    // Remove padding manually
    int pad_len = plaintext[plaintext_len - 1];
    if (pad_len > 0 && pad_len <= AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
        plaintext_len -= pad_len;
        ftruncate(fileno(of), plaintext_len);  // Adjust file length to remove padding
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    fclose(cf);
    fclose(kf);
    fclose(of);
}

void compute_sha512_224(const char *input_file, const char *digest_file) {
    FILE *inf = fopen(input_file, "rb");
    FILE *df = fopen(digest_file, "rb");

    if (!inf || !df) {
        perror("File error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    if (!mdctx) handleErrors();

    if (EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, EVP_sha512_224(), NULL) != 1) handleErrors();

    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int len;
    while ((len = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, inf)) > 0) {
        if (EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, buffer, len) != 1) handleErrors();
    }

    unsigned char hash[SHA512_224_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned int hash_len;
    if (EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, hash, &hash_len) != 1) handleErrors();
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);

    unsigned char expected_hash[SHA512_224_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    if (fread(expected_hash, 1, SHA512_224_DIGEST_LENGTH, df) != SHA512_224_DIGEST_LENGTH) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading expected hash\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (memcmp(hash, expected_hash, SHA512_224_DIGEST_LENGTH) == 0) {
        printf("Hashes match\n");
    } else {
        printf("Hashes do not match\n");
    }

    fclose(inf);
    fclose(df);
}

void encrypt_camellia_256_ofb(const char *input_file, const char *key_file, const char *output_file) {
    FILE *inf = fopen(input_file, "rb");
    FILE *kf = fopen(key_file, "rb");
    FILE *of = fopen(output_file, "wb");

    if (!inf || !kf || !of) {
        perror("File error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    unsigned char key[32];
    unsigned char iv[16] = {0};  // Initialize IV to 0

    if (fread(key, 1, 32, kf) != 32) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading key\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (!ctx) handleErrors();

    if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_camellia_256_ofb(), NULL, key, iv) != 1) handleErrors();

    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned char ciphertext[BUFFER_SIZE + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    int len;
    int ciphertext_len = 0;

    while ((len = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, inf)) > 0) {
        int out_len;
        if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &out_len, buffer, len) != 1) handleErrors();
        fwrite(ciphertext, 1, out_len, of);
        ciphertext_len += out_len;
    }

    if (EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext, &len) != 1) handleErrors();
    fwrite(ciphertext, 1, len, of);
    ciphertext_len += len;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    fclose(inf);
    fclose(kf);
    fclose(of);
}

int main(void) {
    decrypt_aes_128_ecb("s83660-cipher.bin", "s83660-source-key.bin", "decrypted.jpg");
    compute_sha512_224("decrypted.jpg", "s83660-digest.bin");
    encrypt_camellia_256_ofb("decrypted.jpg", "s83660-dest-key.bin", "s83660-dest-cipher.bin");

    return 0;
}


Output
Key after modification: 000db08f3b6c505d76e9e88962e94c57
Intermediate plaintext length: 102224
139956396554048:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:646:
Aborted (core dumped)


Steps I’ve Taken:
Verified the key length is 16 bytes.
Corrected the first byte of the key as instructed.
Attempted to disable automatic padding and handle it manually.

My Environment:
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1
GCC version: 9.3.0
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

My Questions:
Why am I getting the EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt error even though the key and data seem correct?
Is there an issue with the way I'm handling the padding manually?
Are there additional steps I can take to debug this issue?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Since the bug is localized in decrypt_aes_128_ecb(), there is actually no need to post compute_sha512_224() and encrypt_camellia_256_ofb(). Neither is required for a repro of the problem.

The line key[0] = 0; // Salting is strange. I don't see any relation to salting here. Was this handled in the same way for encryption? What can you say at all about encryption? Are you sure that the encryption logic and decryption logic match and that the data is consistent? Can you share the encryption code or some test data?

Thank you for the feedback. Here is some additional context about the encryption process and the rationale behind modifying the key.
The encryption was performed using AES-128-ECB. The key for decryption is provided in s83660-source-key.bin, and I was instructed to modify the first byte of the key by setting it to 0 before using it for decryption. The rationale provided was that this should be treated as a "salt," though I agree this usage is unconventional.

For a repro we need the encryption code or test data. Can you provide these or at least one of the two?

I was instructed to modify the first byte of the key by setting it to 0 before using it for decryption. ?!?!????  Huh?  All that does is reduce the entropy in the key.  And given that error:06065064 seems to mean something like "bad key" it seems beyond misguided and flat-out wrong.  Have you tried decrypting without corrupting, err, "salting" the key?

OT: And don't use AES/ECB as it's not secure.

...Is there an issue with the way I'm handling the padding manually?... Hard to answer without information on the encryption and the padding used there. If PKCS#7 padding is applied during encryption, you do not need to disable padding, as OpenSSL uses PKCS#7 by default.

If no PKCS#7 padding was used during encryption, then the default padding must indeed be disabled. However, according to the documentation EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding() should be called after EVP_DecryptInit_ex() (here). Presumably the padding is not disabled in your code and if no PKCS#7 was used during encryption, this would generally raise an exception in EVP_DecryptFinal_ex() and could well be the cause of the issue.

2 more notes: 1. The line int pad_len = plaintext[plaintext_len - 1] seems to be incorrect. plaintext is a buffer of size BUFFER_SIZE + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH (1024 + 32 = 1056), while plaintext_len is the total size of the decrypted data, which can be larger. 2. The unpadding you currently implement reads the padding size from the last byte (as PKCS#7 does). Check if this is consistent with the padding (otherwise unpadding will generally corrupt the decrypted data).

To summarize: Don't do key[0] = 0;  // Salting (unless the real key is actually the key in the file, but with a 0 in position 0...), disable padding after calling init. (But why the manual handling?) Change plaintext_len += out_len; to plaintext_len = out_len; in the read loop.

Caution, with the fix from the previous comment plaintext_len = out_len the current unpadding generally no longer works. Use e.g. a 2nd variable for the size of the current data in the buffer.
